# Leaving parenthesis in method call

Tags: scala, methods

I thought in Scala we can leave paratnehsis when calling methods. I tried to do this, but compiler complains:

```
object Objd {
  def m1(s: String) = {
    StringBuilder.newBuilder
      .append(s)
      .toString()
  }

  def m2(s : Stirng) = {
    StringBuilder.newBuilder
      .append("Another string")
      .append(";")
      .append(m1 s)  //compile error. Not applicable to String
      .toString()
  }
}
```

Why isn't it possible in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in general. The rule is that

```
expr m1 arg1 m2 arg2 ...
```

means

```
expr.m1(arg1).m2(arg2)...
```

In this case you don't have a start to the chain. You could write `append(this m1 s)`.